# FreeBSD on ARM architecture?

Tags: freebsd, arm, camera

Can FreeBSD be used for ARM architecture devices? Also, is there a camera driver for FreeBSD?

Comment: In the future, please don't mix unrelated questions; you can just ask more than one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There is [a port of FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/platforms/arm.html) to the ARM architecture, however you might need to adapt it to your needs.
2. If "camera driver" refers to webcams, [some models are supported](http://wiki.freebsd.org/WebcamCompat).

Comment: what about if I was making a digital camera?

Comment: @Coder404 then you'd likely have to write your own device drivers, depending on what hardware you're using (e.g. circuits to capture/process the image from the sensors).

Comment: ugh. That will take forever! Is there an open source camera os, specifically freeBSD or linux that you know of?

Comment: @Coder404 As far as I can tell, there isn't, each camera manufacturer uses its own custom operating system, or at least their custom tools running on another operating system (I belive that it will likely be a real-time OS like QNX).

Comment: O.k. Can QNX be ported to ARM processors?

Comment: @Coder404 QNX works on ARM but it's commercial software (not open-source), you will have to contact them to discuss your needs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3023/discussion-between-coder404-and-renan)